# include in line r code in markdown with column which name uses the grave accent

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

how can I include in line r code in markdown when column name called uses ` character (grave accent)?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
df <- as.data.frame(c(9,3,4))
colnames(df) <- c("Depth (cm)")
```

The mean depth is `r mean(df$`Depth (cm)`)`
````

I get "Error in parse(text = code, keep.source = FALSE)".

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Tony, can you edit your question to include a reproducible example that we can cut and paste into our own R sessions, and write what you would like the output to look like? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I know how to include r code... but how do I include markdown code? apologies

Comment: same way, just cut and paste the YAML header and the minimum relevant code chunks and indent four spaces and we can reproduce and hopefully help you find a solution

Comment: Or also `r mean(df[,1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
df <- as.data.frame(c(9,3,4))
colnames(df) <- c("Depth (cm)")
```

The mean depth is `r mean(df$"Depth (cm)")`
````

Comment: or `df[["Depth (cm)"]]`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
df <- as.data.frame(c(9,3,4))
colnames(df) <- c("Depth (cm)")
```

The mean depth is `r mean(df[,1])`
````

produces

[image]